# Alignment of an Input Group Addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to move the input group addon (DisplayPaid) left so that it aligns against the right hand side of a fixed width input.  Currently it pulls to the right hand side of the screen.

```
  <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></span>
        <select id="ddlCategory" asp-for="SelectedCompanyID" asp-items="Model.Companies" class="form-control"></select>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><input id="chkDisplayPaid" type="checkbox" asp-for="DisplayPaid"/> Display Paid</span>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6h0L9t97/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox** to achieve this, Add the following CSS more:

```
.input-group {
  display: flex;
}

.input-group-addon {
  flex-basis: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Aligning items vertically center */
  justify-content: center; /* Aligning items horizontally center */
}

/* You can use a new class name as well */
.input-group-addon:last-child {
  flex-basis: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Aligning items vertically center */
  justify-content: center; /* Aligning items horizontally center */
}
```

Have a look at the updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h0L9t97/2/)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That seems to work, but it does have the undesired effect of moving the icons up slightly higher and no longer vertically centered.  Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: @Reafidy Updated my answer, please have a look. It should be sorted now.